# Logging Queries with execution time with PDO - autocomplete not working

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to make an intermediate class which will log the queries in an array along with their execution time. Everything is fine and it works perfectly. But autocomplete doesnt work when i try to access the intermediate class. How can get the autocomplete to work. I am using Netbeans.

Intermediate classname is Model.

From my application, i have a class by the name Users which extends Model.

```
class Users extends Model
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $stmt = $this->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? ');

        $stmt->bindValue(1, 1); //$stmt-> auto-complete is unavailable
        $stmt->execute();

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        print_r($rows); //i get results
    }
}
```

My Model class looks like this.

```
class Model extends PDO
{
    public static $log = array();
    private $query_cache = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            "mysql:dbname=".MYSQL_DB.";host=".MYSQL_HOST,
            MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD
        );
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $time = "";
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $query ));

        if (key_exists($query,$this->query_cache)
            && is_object($this->query_cache[$query]))
        {
            $result = $this->query_cache[$query];
        } else {
            $start = microtime(true);
            $result = parent::query($query);
            $time = microtime(true) - $start;
            $this->query_cache[$query] = $result;
            Logger::$logText['DATABASE'][] = array(
                'QUERY' => $query,
                'TIME'  => number_format($time,4)
            );
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return LoggedPDOStatement
     */
    public function prepare($query) {
        return new LoggedPDOStatement(parent::prepare($query));
    }
}
```

My LoggedPDOStatement looks like this.

```
class LoggedPDOStatement
{
    /**
     * The PDOStatement we decorate
     */
    private $statement;

    public function __construct(PDOStatement $statement) {
        $this->statement = $statement;
    }

    /**
     * When execute is called record the time it takes and
     * then log the query
     * @return PDO result set
     */
    public function execute() {
        $start = microtime(true);
        $result = $this->statement->execute();
        $time = microtime(true) - $start;
        Model::$log[] = array(
            'query' => '[PS] ' . $this->statement->queryString,
            'time'  => round($time * 1000, 3)
        );
        return $result;
    }
    /**
     * Other than execute pass all other calls to the PDOStatement object
     * @param string $function_name
     * @param array $parameters arguments
     */
    public function __call($function_name, $parameters) {
        return call_user_func_array(
            array($this->statement, $function_name), $parameters
        );
    }
}
```

Is their any better way of doing this ?

Comment: Why extending PDO ? You may consider reading about [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: You know, you don't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` when using PDO *correctly* because you should be doing prepared statements.

Comment: @Touki, thats why i am asking is their any better solution that this ?

Comment: @cillosis yes thats correct. But I am not using mysql_real_escape_string anywhere in my code. My question is 1) how can i get the autocomplete to work. 2) Is their any better solution to log queries and its execution time.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha #1) You are using `mysql_real_escape_string()` in `Model->query()`. #2) You are calling `parent::prepare($query)` in the parameter to the logger and then again inside the logging function itself. The PDO prepare() method returns a PDOStatement object (or false)...not a string...and the PDOStatement object does not have a `prepare()` method. Your `Model->prepare()` logic should be this instead: `return new LoggedPDOStatement($query);`

Comment: @cillosis Thanks. Sorry about mysql_real_escape_string. I didn't mean to use it but i guess its my coding practice that i used it.

I understand your #1 and #2. But if i just use return new LoggedPDOStatement($query); i am not able to log the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this taking suggestions from @cillosis and @Touki

@Touki, i agree i shouldnt extend the PDO Class.
@cillosis, thanks for your comments.

This is the way i have written my class. I have not pasted the full code as its not complete yet. But i have checked it works. And i can log my queries as well. However i am not sure if i will be able to log the execution time.

```
class Model
{
    /**
     * The singleton instance
     *
     */
    static private $PDOInstance;

    public function __construct($dsn="", $username = false, $password = false, $driver_options = false) {
        if (!self::$PDOInstance) {
            try {
                self::$PDOInstance = new PDO(
                    "mysql:dbname=".MYSQL_DB.";host=".MYSQL_HOST,
                    MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD
                );
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die("PDO CONNECTION ERROR: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
            }
        }
        return self::$PDOInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Initiates a transaction
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function beginTransaction() {
        return self::$PDOInstance->beginTransaction();
    }

    public function prepare($statement, $driver_options = false) {
        //log the $statement
        if (!$driver_options)
            $driver_options = array();
        return self::$PDOInstance->prepare($statement, $driver_options);
    }
}
```